# security best practices for a public POST URL

Tags: django, json, security

I'm writing a simple blog using Django, and I'm including a Python CLI script that will allow me to post an entry by sending it as JSON to `blog.com/post`. Now I obviously don't want anyone to be able to post an entry on my blog, so I'll need to take some security measures.

It seems like a password passed as a URL parameter is a good place to start -- I'll send a POST to `blog.com/post?key=foobar`. Just to be on the safe side, I should store this on the server salted and hashed. Is this all that will be necessary? I'm also planning on putting the code up on Github when it's ready; will this affect any security decisions I make?

Comment: I agree with @ArgsKwargs. Just use django-tastypie. But, if you want to go on your own *don't* put a password in the querystring. Implement OAuth with something like django-oauth or django-social-auth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tbh I wouldn't bother reinventing the wheel, have a look at django-tastypie which implements a few good ways achieving REST calls. It ships with django and api key authentication (and a few more) and lets you add custom authentication behaviour